# Pushing a branch having multiple features to remote

Tags: git, github

Branch Structure is as follows ( for local rep)
master -> A -> f1 -> f2
(where master, A, f1, f2 are branches)

I want to push f1 to branch A. However, I am not sure whether pushing f1 to remote would also push f2.

PS I only want f1 to be pushed.

Comment: What are f1 and f2? Commits or branches?

Comment: Unclear. What is a "branch structure"? What does "push f1 to branch A" mean?

Comment: Have made edits for more clarity in the question

Comment: By saying _pushing f1 to branch A_, do you mean **merging** f1 into A?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by saying *push `f1` to `A`* you actually mean **merge `f1` into `A`**.

If:

- `f2` is a child of `f1` (created from `f2` as base)
- and assuming no commits of `f2` was merged in `f1`

Then merging `f1` to `A` won't merge any commits made on `f2`

Comment: That's true, but `git push` never does any merging... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Branches are not really relevant here, not the way you are thinking at least.

When you run `git push`, you supply:

- a *remote name* such as `origin` (or some alternative), and
- a *refspec* (technically, any number of refspecs, but you'll be supplying exactly one).

The *refspec* consists of two parts, a *source* and a *destination* (with an optional prefix `+` to set the per-refspec *force flag;* this flag is set automatically on all refspecs if you use `--force`).  A full, and fully-qualified, refspec always includes both the source and destination and each part starts with `refs/`.

In other words, you might run:

```
git push origin refs/heads/f1:refs/heads/for-you
```

The *source* part, which appears on the left side of the colon, causes your own Git software to run `git rev-parse` to turn this fully-qualified branch name into a raw hash ID.  The resulting hash ID is the hash ID of the *last* of the commits that your `git push` is going to send.

Your Git—by which I mean your computer's Git software suite, operating on your own Git repository—then calls up the server's Git (the server's software suite, operating on a completely separate Git repository over on the server).  Your Git asks their Git if they need the commit whose hash ID your Git has figured out here.  They either say:

- *Yes, please send that commit, and tell me about its parent commit hash IDs too.*

or:

- *No thanks, I already have that commit.*

If they *don't* have the commit, your Git is now obligated to ask whether they want the commit's parent or parents.  For each of those hash IDs, they will either say *Do send that one, and tell me about the parents* or *No thanks, I already have that one* as before.

This conversation repeats until your Git has either committed to send to them *every* commit from this last commit on backwards, or has run out of commits that they don't have, whichever occurs first.  Your Git now packages up all of those commits, including any files that must go with them, and delivers the entire package to their Git.  They now have access to *every historical commit leading up to and including the final commit* that you chose for your *`source`*.

Now that the other Git has all these commits, your Git uses the *`destination`* part you supplied.  Your Git now asks their Git to set *their* branch.  Given:

```
git push origin refs/heads/f1:refs/heads/for-you
```

this is *their* branch named `for-you`.  They now decide whether they will allow you to set their `for-you` branch to have, as its final commit, the hash ID you got when your Git ran `git rev-parse` on your branch name `f1`.

**If** (this is a very large "if") you run:

```
git push origin refs/heads/f1
```

—in other words, if you *leave out the colon*—then here, your Git assumes the *same name* on *both sides of this operation*.  That is, your Git figures out the hash ID that goes with your branch name `f1`, and then asks them to set *their* branch name `f1` as well.

You may further abbreviate your branch names by leaving out `refs/heads/` entirely, as in:

```
git push origin f1
```

Your Git takes this ambiguous name `f1` and searches around throughout your Git repository to see what kind of name `f1` is.  Is it a branch name?  Is it a tag name?  Is it perhaps both a branch name *and* a tag name?

If it is *only* a branch name, your Git assumes you meant `refs/heads/f1`, i.e., the branch name `f1`.  So this becomes:

```
git push origin refs/heads/f1
```

which in turn becomes:

```
git push origin refs/heads/f1:refs/heads/f1
```

If `f1` is a *tag* name, however, your Git chooses the *tag* name first.  That applies even if `f1` is *both* a branch name *and* a tag name.  So if you're not absolutely certain that `f1` will always resolve to *just* a branch name, it's wise to *fully qualify* the name—at least in a *script* that will be run unattended—by spelling out `refs/heads/f1`.  (If you're doing the `git push` while watching the result, you'll see if you pushed a branch or tag, so it's reasonably safe to use the shorthand.)

Note that none of this depends in any way on the existence of *any other branch or tag names in either repository*.  Your Git is simply going to look up `f1`, to see if it's a branch or tag name.  If it's only a branch name, your Git is then going to use that name to look up a commit hash ID on your side, and send that commit along with its history to their Git, and then ask their Git to set *their* branch name `f1` so that it ends at the same commit that is the last commit on *your* branch name `f1`.